# Numbering of a table starting from the second table

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering, caption

I have three tables. I want to use the Caption feature of MS Word to number the tables automatically. I want the numbering to start from the second table which means that the second table will have a caption like "Table 1: Data from Survey". How do I accomplish this?

When I click on "Insert Caption" while my cursor is on the second table, it automatically shows Table 2 in the Caption box which cannot be edited from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish that you use the Restart Numbering Switch, which is a `\r#` added to the SEQ field.

Process ... add the Captions, but don't get concerned about the sequence number. Your tables will be numbered Table 1, Table 2 and Table 3.

Then toggle the sequence number fields (`Alt + F9`) and correct the field coding so that it looks like the example below. Toggle the fields back to showing the result and you're done.

[image]